# How to place image texture over procedural texture?

Tags: texturing, shaders

My main target is to put image texture over procedural glass texture. I try to follow youtube tutorial(1 image), i just started, but i faced two problems. First in tutorial BSDF overlay each over, in my case they mix with each over. Second when i connect alpha channel of image texture with Fac of Mix shader my image texture gone black.
Did i missed something or it`s all because of different versions?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: To make transparency work in eevee, you must change your material's **Blend Mode** away from _Opaque_ (In the material properties tab).

Comment: I try alpha clip and alpha hashed, this make no difference. With alpha blend model start looking glass-like, but image texture dissapeared at all.

Comment: Mix Shader node will output as much % of the 2nd shader as specified by `Fac`tor input. *Alpha* value that you send there says `0` for complete transparency and `1` (100%) for complete opaqueness. So in your setup completely opaque parts of the image are replaced by the shader not using the image - you want to switch the shader inputs so that for 100% opaque parts of the image you display only the image.